# Can I prevent my Windows laptop from waking up when the lid opens?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep, power-management

My laptop (a Lenovo Thinkpad W530 running Windows 7) regularly wakes from a sleep state in my bag, draining battery and overheating badly (even when I make a point to leave the fans unobstructed by its sleeve, and adjust power settings to automatically return it to sleep after a short interval).  Inputting "powercfg -lastwake" in the terminal informs me that the wake is due to the the lid being opened.  I assume this means that there's a problem with the lid's magnet sensor, but I'd rather not open up the casing and tinker with that.  Is there any software solution for requiring a press of the power button to wake the computer from sleep / disabling the automatic wake on lid "opening"?

(Notes: I've tried going into the Device Manager to tinker with the lid but don't see any power management options; nor do I see options in the Power Management menus.  Hibernation doesn't work reliably on my system, I don't want to have to do a full shutdown every time I change locations, and I like the convenience of triggering sleep with a lid-close.  I dualboot Linux Mint but I'm using Microsoft OneNote for my dissertation research, so a Windows solution would be preferable.)

Comment: Can you disable the lid switch in BIOS? I have a feeling that this is something you won't be able to do...

Comment: Hibernation does not work reliably on most windows systems... Did either the answer or the comment solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could just disable the sleep-on-close-lid option, which should in turn prevent a wakeup when you open the lid. However, you'll then need to remember to put the laptop to sleep before closing the lid (the power button can be configured to do this).

Comment: Good enough for now on a Dell XPS 15 9560.