# How to setup the laptop behavior when opening the LID

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep, power-management, hibernate

I'm using Windows 7 When i set my laptop to sleep or hibernate.

But when i open the lid the laptop start automatically : this cause a problem for me because when i package the laptop in my hand bag , the lid start to open a little bit so the laptop start itself ....

i don't want to do nothing when i open the lid , however i want to manually press the power button so the laptop have to wake up from sleep/hibernate mode.

I look at the power settings but there is no way to configure action when the lid is opened.

Thanks.

Comment: You should specify the OS you're running, the laptop make/model and manufacturer. Each laptop is different. There is probably a magnet or button embedded into the monitor's bezel that triggers sleep/wake when you open or close the lid.

Comment: @abnev sorry i forgot to mention it but i have added as a tag ... ok it's windows 7 , but also i have the same issue in ubuntu but i do my work most of the time in windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows OS: Go to Control Panel → Power Options → choose how the lid behaves.

Comment: I can choose how the laptop behave when the lid is closed but not when it's opened !!!

Comment: Have you tried setting 'close lid' to 'do nothing', this should stop the opening wake from happening.  Same topic as here http://superuser.com/questions/778169/can-i-prevent-my-windows-laptop-from-waking-up-when-the-lid-opens?rq=1

Comment: @Cand3r yes that exactly what i want to do thanks ... Don't know why windows haven't included this option !