# Disable wake on lid open for Windows 10

Tags: windows, laptop, sleep, power-management

### On a laptop with Windows 10, how do I disable 'wake on lid open'?

It's surprisingly hard to find answers to this question.  My bag's magnets wake up my laptop from sleep, in the bag, randomly

I have already disabled sleep on lid close, but it does not solve the issue of magnets tripping the lid sensor and waking it from sleep.

I've also disabled 'ACPI Lid' in device manager, no dice.

(To be clear, this means 'disable sleep on lid close' function **does not** fix this, that's the issue.  It disables lid close, but not **lid open**)

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://superuser.com/questions/778169/can-i-prevent-my-windows-laptop-from-waking-up-when-the-lid-opens?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately not, that prevents sleep on lid close, but does not disable open-lid-wake

Comment: If nothing else works, use *hibernate*, instead, and it will also save battery life (at the expense of a few seconds when starting).

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Windows 10 have added an option for "Lid open action" in Power Options,
which you may change to "Do nothing":

[image]

To get to Power Options:

- Run *Settings > Power Options*
- Click "Change plan settings" on your chosen power plan
- Click "Change advanced power settings"

If you don't see a "Lid open action" in Power Options, create and run a `.reg` file
containing (reboot might be required):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347\99ff10e7-23b1-4c07-a9d1-5c3206d741b4]
"Attributes"=dword:00000002
```

An alternative to the `.reg` file would be to run the command:

```
powercfg -attributes SUB_BUTTONS 99ff10e7-23b1-4c07-a9d1-5c3206d741b4 -ATTRIB_HIDE
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can still get it to un-sleep on both lid open and with lid closed + my bag magnet, so no dice.  Thanks for the effort regardless!

Comment: Do you mean that Lid open action" doesn't work? Does it perhaps work when opening the lid by hand (not with the magnet)?

Comment: Also, @EllyArd please notice there are 2 settings for lid open action (one for on battery and one for on power lead). Have you got the right one set (or both set) for your requirements?